# Set Bootstrap row height to fill height but also be constrained by the height of a container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Probably a simple question.. I have a container. That container has X number of rows. The rows should fill the container completely, height-wise. The rows should not expand outside of the container. I don't want to manually set the height of the rows.

If I set `class="h-100"` to the rows, the first one takes the full height of the container, the others render outside of the container... I would think that the parent's height would set the height constraint for the inner elements...

I feel like this should be simple but I can't seem to find the right combination of classes/styling.

```
<html lang="en" style="
    height: 100%;
"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>
  <body style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
      <div class="row">row 1</div>
      <div class="row">row 2</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For reference this is the cleanest solution I found.
It seems to be a feature of flexbox (d-flex class), to share the available space, using `flex-fill`.

But by default it will share available `width`. Setting `flex-column` changes the direction so that it shares available `height`.

```
<html lang="en" style="
    height: 100%;
"><head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body style="
    height: 100%;
">
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
    
  <div class="flex-fill">
      ROW 1 
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill">
      ROW 2 
  </div>

  <div class="flex-fill">
      ROW 3 
  </div>

</div>
  
</body></html>
```